# Are few closed questions a bad sign?

Tags: discussion, closed-questions, stackexchange-2.0, beta-phase

I'm participating in the [RPG stack exchange community](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/2208/role-playing-games).  I've noticed that unlike [other sites](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/search?q=closed%3A1), there are <strike>zero</strike> very few closed questions.  Obviously it's necessary to [allow more subjectiveness](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/50/how-much-subjectiveness-is-ok) on a site that discusses *role playing* games, but I think it very odd, that the community hasn't found <strike>any</strike>many questions it agrees are out of line.

Is a lack of closed questions a bad sign, or am I being uptight? (go ahead and say it Welbog)

Comment: There are no closed questions on RPG? [What makes a game an “Indie” RPG? ](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/700/what-makes-a-game-an-indie-rpg-closed) and [Proven starting level intra-party Combo's (synergistic tactics)](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/790/proven-starting-level-intra-party-combos-synergistic-tactics-closed) are closed... we have _some_ but there's only 5ish.

Comment: @Richard Apparently I was searching incorrectly before?

Comment: @C. Ross - I see... but you have an interesting point; we seem to have very, very few closed.

Comment: It's funny to read this when we already have people whining on cooking.SE about too many closed questions.  No matter what you do, you can't win.  *le sigh*

Comment: @Aarobot Same on gaming.  Still from what we've seen on the trilogy, many close is not a bad thing.  We don't know the effect of two few close votes.

Answer (score 1):

A lack of closed questions by itself isn't a bad sign.  It's only bad if there are questions that *should* be closed but aren't.  <strike>I'm not sure what the thresholds are for voting to close on new sites, but</strike> it's possible that there aren't enough people with enough rep to vote to close.  If there are specific questions that need attention, they should be flagged for moderator (DM?) attention, or brought up on the [RPG meta site](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/) for discussion.

Comment: During the private beta, anyone can vote to close. During the public beta, anyone with at least 500 reputation can vote to close - this actually precedes both split vote count and editing abilities.

Comment: Ah, thanks @Grace.  It looks like that might be it.  It seems that only 11 people currently have the vote-to-close right on RPG.